# How to return the points {Xi,Zi} generated by ContourPlot

Tags: plotting

I have the following two questions

1. How to visualize the dependence Y versus X with Mathematica using   ContourPlot, if  it is given by the following  system of two equations:

   Y=f(X,Z) and g(X,Z)=0
2. How to return the points {Xi,Zi} generated by ContourPlot  applied to g(X,Z)=0  that visualizes Z=q(X).

Remark 1: The answer on the second question resolves evidently the problem formulated in the first question 
Remark 2: In fact the problem formulated in the first question may be effectively solved without ContourPlot by differentiating in X both equations, and numerical solving the resulting system of 2 ordinary differential eqs

Any help and suggestions are  appreciated.

Comment: Hello, Yuri ! You would have to add a simple working example to illustrate the functionality and you should format your code properly - To do so, please, refer to the documentation centre.

Comment: For your second question, there are [several examples](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=extract+contours) on this site of extracting contours from `ContourPlot`. I don't understand the first question, surely a function like y[x] depending on only one parameter would be visualised with `Plot`

Comment: Thanks all for your comments, I edited my questions to make them more clear

Comment: As Sektor suggested, can you please post a simple working example with definitions of $f$ and $g$ so that people have something to work with?

Comment: My own functions are too complicate in order to be used as an example, while I rather need in the general solution. By the way Matlab provides returning of the points generated by the contour plot that defines the contour (as asked in question 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this is what you are looking for:

```
g[x_, z_] := x^3 + z
f[x_, z_] := x - z^2
```

Create a contour plot of `g[x, z] == 0`

```
cp = ContourPlot[g[x, z] == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Extract the `{x, z}` coordinates of the line:

```
xz = First@Cases[Normal@cp, Line[data_] :> data, -1];
```

Create a list of `{x, y}` coordinates using `y = f[x, z]`:

```
xy = {#, f[##]} & @@@ xz;
```

Plot the line of `y` vs `x`:

```
ListLinePlot[xy]
```

[image]

Comment: Simon, many thanks for your answer. I'm a beginner in Wolfram Math., and I will check your solution. Yuri